# Need Help Understanding a Differential Equation Problem

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I hope you're doing well. I'm a first-year mathematics student in a French preparatory program, and I'm currently working on a challenging exercise involving differential equations. I've made some progress, but I'm stuck.

The exercise is as follows:

Consider finding all functions $f: (1, +\infty) \rightarrow (1, +\infty)$, differentiable, such that for every $x$ belonging to $(1, +\infty)$, the following equation holds:

$
(x-1)f'(x) = (x-1)f(x)^2 + (2-x^2)f(x) + x^2 - x - 1
$
Next, find a constant solution $K$. Then, define $h(x) = f(x) - K$. Determine the differential equation satisfied by $h$. Let $g(x) = \frac{1}{h(x)}$. Find the differential equation satisfied by $g$. Finally, draw conclusions based on the analysis.

I managed to find one constant solution $ K = 1 $, but I'm struggling to understand how to proceed further. The next steps involve defining a new function $ h(x) = f(x) - K $ and determining the differential equation satisfied by $ h $. After that, I'm supposed to define $ g(x) = \frac{1}{h(x)} $ and find the differential equation satisfied by $ g $.

If anyone could offer some guidance or insight into how to approach this problem, I would greatly appreciate it. I'm eager to learn and understand the steps involved in solving this type of problem.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Substitute $f=h+1$ into the original equation and you will get the equation satisfied by $h.$ Next substitute $h=1/g$ into the obtained equation. Then you twill obtain the equation satisfied by $g.$ I haven't checked the calculations but the equation satisfied by $g$ should be simple enough for determining all the solutions.

Comment: Indeed: the D.E. for $g$ is linear. Once you find $g,$ your get $h$ and finally $f.$